# Get subfolder by name and navigate Webrowser to that path

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have combobox that has folder names (which are located in my C:\ subfolders) as Items. I want to navigate my Webrowser according to selected folder name in my combobox. Here is what I tried:

```
Dim myDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\", MyCombo.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

          WebBrowser1.Navigate(myDirectories)
```

How must I search subfolders to make this work ? I get error: "The address specified cannot exist." in webrowser control.

EDIT (to make myself a bit more clear):

Example - there is a folder named Test and folder named Example....They are located both in C:\ but different subfolders - like "C:\Windows\Test" and "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Example".

1. I select "Test" or "Example" from Combobox Items;
2. Then by code, Webrowser should navigate to that folder URL on my PC.

So code should search all folders/subfolders by the name as in Combobox, and then pass path to Webbrowser URL if any matching criteria.

Comment: Try to do it yourself in your browser, when you have it working then you'll have the format needed to use for the url.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you, I'm vb.net beginner. Format is the issue ?

Comment: Why not just `WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\"+MyCombo.Text)`

Comment: @Hackerman, nice to know I can do that too, but this doesn't work. FOLDER has to be searched first, It's somewhere in my C:\ subfolders. If MyCombo.Text = "Example" then your suggestion just points to C:\Example\, nothing else. And I have my folders in different subfolders...

Comment: Ok but you need to remember that `Directory.GetDirectories` returns an array of String and that is why your code is not working..if you have any doubt just ask me :)

Comment: Well I need path of certain folder and paste It in Webrowser URL, simple as that. Your solution doesn't do that, I need path of folder that is selected from combobox.

Comment: First of all is a comment, not a solution...I was trying to point out that your code doesn't works because you was using an array in your `Navigate` method...still your code seems to make no sense

Comment: Well If I would post whole code, nobody would even bother. It's a treeview node_click event - when user clicks on It, new form on tabcontrol is being created and this form shows webrowser with desired path on PC. Here you can view/drag/drop files etc., like in windows explorer (and without any other contents on local hard drive, like Explorer shows). And path opened is the folder name you select from combobox. Everything works now, except checking If folder does even exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This is how I did it, feel free to suggest something better:

```
Dim myDirectory = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\", MyCombo.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

 For Each folder As String In myDirectory

            WebBrowser1.Navigate(folder)
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strFiles As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\")
    For Each sDir As String In strFiles
        ListBox1.Items.Add(sDir)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListBox1.Items.Count > -1 Then
        Process.Start("explorer", ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how could I use this with Webbrowser, I don't have Listbox ? And folder name is getting from combobox ?

Comment: What do you mean ? It works just fine for me - I can see my local paths as in Windows Explorer with all features (cut/copy/paste/drag/drop...).

Answer (score 0):

Why use a web browser for local paths? Web browser is for Internet and that's why you get the error as it's looking for http not c:\.

Replace Listbox with Combobox instead

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strFiles As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\")
    For Each sDir As String In strFiles
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(sDir)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.Items.Count > -1 Then
        Process.Start("explorer", ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you so wish you can use that ListBox to hold the list of files in that chosen directory which removes the web browser control completely

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim strFiles As String() = Nothing
    If ComboBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        strFiles = IO.Directory.GetFiles(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each sFile As String In strFiles
            ListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(sFile))
        Next
    End If
End S
```

Comment: Combobox is because It's being populated with Oracle DB table values (and these values are also names of folders on my PC). Lisbox I think would look ugly. there are many DB values. And Webbrowser is because It enables you to drag/drop files, like in Windows Explorer. I use Webbrowser control to open form where I can do that, and only in this folders, without permitting users to see anything else. Opening Windows Explorer shows you all content, and I'm not fammiliar with docking Windows Explorer in forms too. If you know better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Glad you got it solved but it's called a web browser control as it is for browsing websites. Windows Explorer would be better. You say you don't want to give certain users access so why don't you use Windows Security and if a user is in a certain group show or populate the control

Comment: Yes I know windows Explorer would be more appropriate, but It's like a design issue - I need to show only certain directories and not like Window Explorer opens - to imagine, same looks as Webbrowser has (showing Name/Type/Size). It would use Windows Explorer, but I haven't seen anywhere how I could Insert It into form and visually cut It's left side... I'm actually trying wth Listview too, but so many issues, because I need all features (cut/copy/paste/drag/drop, showing icons, navigating through directories, showing folder & file icons, opening files etc.). Any advice would be appreciated.